# Exposing Jenkins to the outside world to receive GitHub webhook requests

Tags: git, github, jenkins, webhooks

I have a Jenkins build server, and my repositories are hosted under an organization on Github.com. I would like to trigger automated builds after a push to the repository on GitHub.com. To enable this, I need to provide my Jenkins server details as a webhook in the settings of Github.com. Is it a good practice to open port 8080 from the server in the trust environment so as to be accessible from GitHub.com?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in order to receive incoming web hooks, you need to make an HTTP endpoint accessible to GitHub. This should only be the webhook URL instead of the complete Jenkins (filtering e.g. through a reverse proxy in front of the installation).

"Accessible to GitHub" still gives you the freedom to restrict the IP addresses that may access this endpoint. The IP addresses used by GitHub are [listed here](https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-ip-addresses/). As of now, they are in the following two networks:

- 192.30.252.0/22
- 185.199.108.0/22